# Как сделать адаптивной бегущую строку?

Tags: html, css

Помогите, пожалуйста, хочу сделать адаптивную строку. Когда я уменьшаю экран, у меня бегущая строка, остается такого же размера, и чем меньше экран, тем мало что там можно разглядеть. Когда пишу height 100%, лента обрезается, и получается не красиво. Буду рада помощи!

```css
.follow__collage {
    display: flex;
    width: 100%;
    justify-content: flex-start;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.follow__collage img {
    width: 100%;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0;
}
.collage.one {
    animation: collage1 50s linear infinite;
}
.collage.two {
    animation: collage2 50s linear infinite;
    position: absolute;
    top:0;
    left: 4px;
}
@keyframes collage1 {
0%{transform: translateX(0%);}

100%{transform: translateX(-100%);}
}
@keyframes collage2 {
0%{transform: translateX(100%);}

100%{transform: translateX(0%);}
}
```

```html
<div class="follow__collage">
            <!--noindex-->
            <a href="#" rel="nofollow noopener noreferrer" target="_blank">
                <img src="https://sun9-38.userapi.com/s/v1/ig2/p5ofBrgV3E0nS0h9Yv5bZJhowuv29zcVMo2UIhoozLCyZvFgG8ac1g-O2Bhl6ypxfK5hNbSMIajp3SfK6jMJEnLi.jpg?size=2282x250&quality=95&type=album" alt="" class="collage one" alt="" class="collage one">
            </a>
            <!--noindex-->
            <!--noindex-->
            <a href="#" rel="nofollow noopener noreferrer" target="_blank">
                <img src="https://sun9-38.userapi.com/s/v1/ig2/p5ofBrgV3E0nS0h9Yv5bZJhowuv29zcVMo2UIhoozLCyZvFgG8ac1g-O2Bhl6ypxfK5hNbSMIajp3SfK6jMJEnLi.jpg?size=2282x250&quality=95&type=album" alt="" class="collage two" alt="" class="collage two">
            </a>
            <!--noindex-->
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Установите для картинок `width: auto`, картинка всё равно "покажется" вся, т.е. она движется в сторону.

```css
.follow__collage {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.follow__collage img {
  width: auto;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0;
}

.collage.one {
  animation: collage1 50s linear infinite;
}

.collage.two {
  animation: collage2 50s linear infinite;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 4px;
}

@keyframes collage1 {
  0% {
    transform: translateX(0%);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateX(-100%);
  }
}

@keyframes collage2 {
  0% {
    transform: translateX(100%);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateX(0%);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="follow__collage">
  <!--noindex-->
  <a href="#" rel="nofollow noopener noreferrer" target="_blank">
    <img src="//i.imgur.com/b1KJTaw.png" alt="" class="collage one" alt="" class="collage one">
  </a>
  <!--noindex-->
  <!--noindex-->
  <a href="#" rel="nofollow noopener noreferrer" target="_blank">
    <img src="//i.imgur.com/b1KJTaw.png" alt="" class="collage two" alt="" class="collage two">
  </a>
  <!--noindex-->
</div>
```

Comment: О, спасибо добрый тебе человек, у меня еще на всех img стоял max-width:100%, я поставила для этой ленты max-width: revert. Спасибо!